# CMake Multiple line comments - Block Comment

Tags: cmake

Is there any way to comment a block in CMake in notepad++ editor?

I have tried searching on Google, but couldn't find much.

Help is needed! Thanks,

Answer (score 188, accepted):

As of CMake 3.0 there is a special syntax for block comments which start with `#[[` and ends with `]]` at the end of block comment. See [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-comment) for further explanation.

You can also put a number of equal signs between the brackets as long as the number between the opening `[[` and closing `]]` are both the same. Ex.

```
#[===[
hello
]] <- this is not the closing
]===]
# ^ this is the closing
```

Some editors and IDEs do not support it yet.

Answer (score 31):

```
if(FALSE) # fake a block comment

endif()
```

Comment: While this works well for *commenting out* a block of valid CMake code, it doesn't allow you write plain text within the `if` block.

Comment: No, it does not unfortunately.. The new cmake 3 syntax looks quite nice though.  I really need to finish updating all my systems and build boxes to cmake 3+

Answer (score 12):

Since CMake version 3.0 there are block comments.

[Example from the CMake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-comment):

```
#[[This is a bracket comment.
It runs until the close bracket.]]
message("First Argument\n" #[[Bracket Comment]] "Second Argument")
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no notion of a block comment in CMake syntax.  However, to comment several lines at once, select the required lines and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

If the file is a .txt file (e.g. CMakeLists.txt), you can either set Notepad++ to always treat .txt files as CMake files (in Settings -> Style configurator select CMakeFile and add " txt" to "User ext.") or for just that file you can set the Language to CMake.

Comment: only CTRL+ Q also does this. I was looking for something like /* */.

Comment: I've updated my answer - good point about about CTRL+Q :-)  There's no CMake equivalent of /*...*/ unfortunately.

Comment: ctrl+q quit my IDE and I burst out laughing